# Guy befriends nameless big brother agent on a giant video screen

Tags: story-identification

I often describe to my friends an old episode of a show i saw on the scifi channel (before they changed the name).  It would have been about the mid to late 90's.  I have the feeling that it started airing earlier (month/year wise than their show "Welcome to Paradox").

The show itself was to emphasize one off shorts by "up and coming" directors, one of which was CGI, another of which featured a guy drowning in his shower (I think, it's possible I'm mixing up multiple shorts shows).

I am looking for a very specific episode of the series.  In it, a man walks into his room in a dystopian facility.  He begins to talk to a face on a giant screen about a number of things, including his day, how embarrassed he was for a coworker who spilled something in the cafeteria, and other seemingly unimportant "how was your day," conversational things.  The face stays quiet throughout this.

At some point, someone outside his room is dragged away by thought police.

Eventually this lonely guy ends up in a montage where he puts on a puppet show for the face and plays a comical game of hide and seek with it in his small room.

Eventually the face loses his cool and tells the guy to knock it off, explaining to the guy that big brother isn't really his friend, but just there to regulate his actions.
With the guy breaking down, crying, and saying, "we'll get through this," the exasperated face shuts off the screen.

So as not to spoil this worse, I won't share the ending (although I imagine it's pretty predictable with that lead up).

With only a yellow belt in Google fu, I have never been able to identify this episode.  It has driven me nuts for years.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this was asked before, but I can't find it.

Comment: That is sort of my problem.  It feels like it should be.  It certainly feels like it could be an easy find, with that much detail, but I can never find any reference to the dumb show.

Comment: please tell us the ending, I'm sure you can edit it so others can choose whether or not read it. A spoiler-box or whatever you'd call it ;)

Comment: Alright, I'm on my phone right now, but I will add that when i get to a computer and figure out how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This is [*Me and the Big Guy*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0192299/), a short film that aired in 1999.**

In case you're interested, I started by spending some time trying to find an appropriate [list of media inspired by 1984](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nineteen_Eighty-Four_in_popular_media), which I eventually spotted (after giving up on the TV section and trying the film section out of desperation) includes a link described thus:

> Me and the Big Guy (1999) is a comedic short-film that satires the relationship between Winston and Big Brother by portraying its main character, Citizen 43275-B, entirely grateful of the Revolution and treating his telescreen as if it were his own best friend.

and that led me to [the film's Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Me_and_the_Big_Guy).

I shan't quote the entire plot, but it's well-described here and the following paragraph in particular seems like enough to consider this a perfect match:

> In much the same manner as an imaginary friend acts, 'The Big Guy' never responds until he finally becomes fed up with Citizen 43275-B and declares that he does not like being called 'The Big Guy' - but this intervention serves only to worsen Big Brother's predicament, as 43275-B enthusiastically hugs the telescreen and goes on to "amuse" him through a variety of ways: sock puppets, Boggle, hide and seek, one-sided pillow fights, and knock-knock jokes.

Comment: Take that, Richard :D

Comment: After this and our conversation on AI,  you are my new favorite person on the board.

Comment: mehehehehe. I was bored so decided to visit your profile and found this question ^_^ Thanks for the challenge

Comment: No, very seriously, thank you.  This has haunted my mind for years.

Comment: In addition, for anyone interested, here's a youtube link to the video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YYQKDqjCEBQ

Comment: @Cone_of_Silence: You're welcome.

Comment: @Cone_of_Silence: Wow, that's pretty cool